# Como converter a data para datetime com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou importando uma planilha do Excel e preciso converter a data para `datetime` para o MySQL aceitar a gravação. Entretanto, já tentei todas as opções do `mutator` do Laravel e não consegui fazer essa conversão.

**Codigo:**

Controller:

```
$import = new ComercialImport

class ComercialImport implements
   ToCollection,
    WithHeadingRow,

public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    /* acredito que teria que mudar aqui na array pois no model nao esta obedecendo, mas nao tenho ideia de como fazer aqui. */
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $com = Comercial::create([
       
           'vigencia_inicial'               => $row  ['vigencial_inicial'],
           'vigencial'                      => $row  ['vigencia_final'],
```

Model:

```
  class Comercial extends Model
     {

        protected $guarded = ['id'];

        public $timestamps = false;
        protected $dates = ['vigencia_inicial', 'Vigencia_final'];
        protected $dateFormat = 'd/m/Y';
```

**Erro:**

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value
```

Comment: eu resolvi com protected $dates  .     
O problema  era na planilha .

Answer (score -2):

Tente utilizar:

$data_inicio = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dates->vigencia_inicial)->format('d/m/Y H:i');
$data_fim = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dates->Vigencia_final)->format('d/m/Y H:i');